# How to fix main function calling the incorrect function when passing parameters? (c++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor

I have a project for my CS class and I have written a copy constructor and am passing an object of the class into it, but the main is calling the wrong constructor.

main:

```
Mammal x;
cout << "Initial values for x: ";
cout << "Age = " << x.getAge() << " Weight = " << x.getWeight() << endl;
x.setAge(10);
x.setWeight(123);
cout << "Modified values for x: ";
cout << "Age = " << x.getAge() << " Weight = " << x.getWeight() << endl;
Mammal w(&x);
cout << "\nModified values for w: ";
cout << "Age = " << w.getAge() << " Weight = " << w.getWeight() << endl;
w.sound();
```

copy constructor:

```
Mammal(Mammal &x)
{
    this->canSwim = x.canSwim;
}
```

function the main is calling:

```
 Mammal(bool x)
{
    canSwim = x;
}
```

I expect the output to copy the values, but it sets the value of age and weight to 0 from the default constructor.

Comment: There is an implicit `bool`conversion going on. Your copy constructor can take the other Mammal as const reference use `Mammal(const Mammal&)` instead. You pass the object by reference into the copy constructor, call `Mammal w(x)`, not `Mammal w(&x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your copy constructor is only copying the canSwim attribute.
You must explicitly tell what attributes you want to copy:

```
Mammal(Mammal &x)
{
    this->canSwim = x.canSwim;
    this->age = x.age;
    this->weight = x.weight;
    ...
}
```

And as pointed out by @Jeffrey Cash, you should remove the "&" from the constructor call.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass by reference, you do not use `&` to get the address of something.

Try the following:

```
Mammal w(x);
```

Also, I suggest using the compilation flags `-Wall -Wextra`, as they would likely have alerted you to this issue.